# Only two out of the three fonts listed in <style> show up

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm having issues with fonts.
I was doing some tests with HTML, and I had three fonts listed. all three are listed exactly the same, as you can see below:

```
<style>
 
   @font-face {
    font-family: 'ktegaki';
    src: url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/0v89ncr2notdcgc/KTEGAKI.ttf);
}
 
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'starlight';
    src: url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/cfcp07kvx3qut4s/starlight.ttf);
}
 
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'romantics';
    src: url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/f9cfrx4wyt13rwv/ROMANTIC.TTF);
}
</style>
```

however, out of the three fonts, only romantics and starlight show up when I insert them into an element. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I've not made any typos when inserting the ktegaki font into any elements. at first I suspected that the dropbox link to the font was broken, that it got deleted, but no—as soon as I copied and pasted it into my browser's search tab and pressed enter, it downloaded the font to the device, so no, it's not an issue with the source.

I tried putting " or ' symbols around the url. Nothing changed.

I was also having an issue with common fonts such as Epilogue or DM Sans, both available on Google Fonts. Both of these fonts were the first in the list. I assumed it somehow was an issue with the font placements, but after swapping those fonts (and the ktegaki font) around, there was still no change. I genuinely have no clue what to do here. It doesn't seem like a browser issue either, it seems like the problem is in the code.

EDIT: by the way, this is how the fonts are inserted into the elements right now (the elements names are edited, they are named differently in the original code):

```
#name1 {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background: white;
border: 3px double #ccc;
border-radius: 0px;
padding: 6px;
overflow: auto;
font-family: Ktegaki;
font-size:10px;
color: #000;
}
 
#name2 {
background: #ccc;
border: 1px solid #000;
border-radius: 7px;
padding: 2px;
color: #000;
font-size: 7px;
font-family: Starlight;
 
}
 
#name3 { 
font-family: Romantics;
font-style: bold;
font-size: 2.5em; 
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-shadow: -1px 0 #fff, 0 1px #000, 1px 0 #000, 0 -1px #fff, 0 0; 
color: #b84154; 
}
```

as mentioned above, only the Romantics and Starlight fonts appear. the Ktegaki font refuses to show up no matter what I do.

EDIT 2: here is the code that I used *after* the  tag:

```
<div id="name1">
<p><div id="name3">Text here</div><mark id="name2">Text here</mark><br><br> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
</div>
```

it's a scrollbox; the ktegaki font was supposed to show up as the multiple "text"s after the second 
.

EDIT 3: just put the code through a validator and turns out that the < /p> end tag after the multiple "text"s (which is where the ktegaki font should be showing up) is getting ignored because it's unexpected...??? very weird. I don't know why it's getting ignored too, it doesn't seem unexpected to me.

EDIT 4: I tried removing the br elements, no difference. Font still doesn't show up.

Comment: How are you inserting the fonts/style to the elements?

Comment: I've just edited the post. I added each element's codes

Comment: Seems to work fine in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cha2o18d/). Consider providing an example that reproduces the unexpected behavior.

Comment: hm, so it seems to be an issue with the code after the style thingy... I've just edited the post including the code for that part

Comment: Please put your code through a validator.

Comment: just did. I edited the post, check it again

Comment: The p element is one of the smallest element in the xhtml tree, you can't place a br element inside it, probably this error invalidates the styles you want

Comment: yep, I tried doing that and it didn't work. The ktegaki font (or any other font I put in its place) still shows up as arial

Comment: I would start by making your HTML valid, you have a stray closing p tag because the system automatically closes the p element when it hits the div. That may or may not be the problem but at least it will stop irrelevant speculation about br tags.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using because I do not see the problem on Windows10 Edge/Chrome with tidy HTML.

Comment: I am using Vivaldi on the latest iOS version. However, I stated before, I do not think it's a browser issue because the font did show up in other files (the jsfiddles in the comments).

Comment: if it also helps, the websites I am using to test the code are w3schools and neocities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's related to the `<p>` tag closing early because there is already a block level element there (the `<div>` tag).  See here:

"Paragraphs are block-level elements, and notably will automatically close if another block-level element is parsed before the closing `</p>` tag. See "Tag omission" below."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

You could change the name3 div to a `<span>` to resolve (although when I put your code in jsfiddle it seems to work as is FYI).

Comment: I tried doing that and the font still doesn't show up. could you send a link to your jsfiddle?

Comment: Try this link: https://jsfiddle.net/#save&togetherjs=spwbSn3SV8

Comment: Or if that doesn't work try this codepen: https://codepen.io/justinmemphis/pen/OJBjBGj